# Broken control panel navigation

Tags: control-panel, navigation

I'm working on a local install of EE 2.10.1 in Windows 7 with XAMPP. Everything is cooperating, but the control panel navigation is broken - mouseing over/clicking nav items shows no drop-down. It appears my JS and CSS are all loading. Default theme. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: Just this:
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
 

ck"),t),i&&r[i](),s.resolve()}};return c.init(),r}()}(jQuery

 
admin.p...3586394 (line 239, col 10521)
TypeError: n.dialog is not a function
 

...e]=function(){$(this).dialog("close")},n.dialog({autoOpen:!1,resizable:!1,modal:...

 
admin.p...3586390 (line 16, col 137)

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall all third party addons, especially Accessories. I literally had this happen to me the other day when I was developing a complex addon. I can't remember if it was the Extension or Accessory that was doing it (pretty sure it was the Accessory). Do them one by one so you can find out exactly who the culprit is.

Comment: Careful "uninstalling all third-party addons" - this will remove all data and settings associated with them, so ensure you have a backup. First try disabling Extensions as this doesn't remove anything.

Comment: Good idea - but this is a fresh install with no third party stuff added.

Comment: So weird! (btw, thank you @PeterLewis, I really should have mentioned that; good catch). I'm pretty damn sure my issue was my project's Accessory adding a `ee()->cp->add_to_foot(' <script> /* JS script */ </script> ');` that landed in a weird spot. What I mean is, is that the script was fine, but the accessory was placing it either after or before another script inclusion that caused a collision in namespace that somehow didn't trigger a browser error.

Comment: It probably doesn't help, but I did run into this same issue cross-browser and OS; which makes me think it is related to a standards behavior. I really wish I could recreate the issue, but it was lost in version control (I purged the branch I was working in, didn't think much of it at the time).